# Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown, outer dimension of 'Const:0' is 12

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, google-cloud-ml

I have created the classification model using [retrain.py](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). Then I deployed the model in google ml engine. It gives the following error

**Create Version failed. Model validation failed: Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown, the outer dimension of 'Const:0' is 12 For more information on how to export Tensorflow SavedModel, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model.**
StackOverflow suggests changing the output tensor dimension

```
def export_model(sess,keys, architecture, saved_model_dir):
 print("reached export funct")
 if architecture == 'inception_v3':
   input_tensor = 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
 elif architecture.startswith('mobilenet_'):
   input_tensor = 'input:0'
 else:
   raise ValueError('Unknown architecture', architecture)
 in_image = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_tensor)
 inputs = {'image': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}

 out_classes = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

 outputs = {'prediction': 
  tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes),
         'classes': 
  tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(tf.convert_to_tensor(list(keys))),}

 signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
  inputs=inputs,
  outputs=outputs,
  method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
  )
 print( 
  tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY)
 legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

 #  Save out the SavedModel.
 builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_dir)
 builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
 sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
 signature_def_map={
   tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: 
    signature
    },
    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
 builder.save()
```

Comment: What is the shape of the tensors  final_result:0 and keys tensor.

Comment: What is the shape of the tensors  final_result:0 and keys tensor. 
Before feeding the input tensor to the graph, CMLE batches all your inputs in the request and creates a tensor with an added extra-dimension. The shape of this extra dimension which is the outermost dimension needs to be arbitrary (because you can have any number of inputs in a request).  The same is done for the outputs. Therefore the outermost dimension for both inputs and outputs needs to be None.

Comment: Bhupesh it will be so helpful if u cud tell me where shud i change in my code..

Comment: What is the code that creates session.graph? That's where the tensor in question is being created. Can you paste that code or relevant lines of that code.